# Back-up Contact before Factory Reset didn't go into vCard format but .txt, how to import it

Tags: contacts

My phone is Lenovo A859.

I did factory reset. Before doing that, they told me to backup my contact and SMS, so I did. After, when I wanted to import my contact, I saw that they saved both as .zip (separated, so I have 2 zips, one for SMS, another for Contact). Meanwhile, later I learnt the Import option on Contact Setting only accepts vCard.

Then I tried to saw the .zip on my desktop. Inside there's a .txt and .mt file. I opened the .txt file. Inside .txt I found a json (AFAIK it's json, CMIIW) formatted like this: (I changed all number to 0)

```
{
  "local_time": 0000000000000,
  "local_number": 000,
  "local_catogary": "contact",
  "ct": [
    {
      "fs": [
        {
          "f": "-1",
          "v": {
            "familyName": "somedude",
            "givenName": "adude"
          },
          "t": "NAME"
        },
        {
          "f": "MOBILE",
          "v": "00000000000",   ---> their phone number
          "t": "PHONE"
        }
      ],
      "op": "add",
      "st": false
    },
    {
      "fs": [
        {
          "f": "-1",
          "v": {
            "middleName": "randude",
            "familyName": "dude",
            "givenName": "dudette"
          },
          "t": "NAME"
        },
        {
          "f": "MOBILE",
          "v": "00000000000",
          "t": "PHONE"
        },
        {
          "f": "HOME",
          "v": "shalalala@dummy.com",
          "t": "EMAIL"
        },
        {
          "f": "YAHOO",
          "v": "yahooId",
          "t": "IM"
        }
      ],
      "op": "add",
      "st": false
    }
  ]
}
```

yah, an array member of `ct` seems to represent a contact: its phone number, email, even yahoo ID is possible. Then inside the `info.mt` file was only this:

```
local_catogary:contact;local_time:0000000000000;local_number:000
```

How do I import these files to my contact? I've tried and my dear phone rejected, saying `"Couldn't import vCard"`, something about `"wrong format"`. Then I tried seeing [Wikipedia's entry of vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard). Seeing vCard format, no wonder it's rejected...

Some things I tried:

1. Changing .txt to .vcf (and later understood why it won't work with this file)
2. Using apps from store (app went weird, won't work)

What file is this? **Is there any way to import this file to my Android phone as Contact**? Or should I program something to convert this to vCard format manually...

Comment: How did you back up your contacts? There may be a way to import them again, using the same tool

Comment: @1990clb YE GOD SHAME ON ME... THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH! From your saying of `the same tool`,  I then went to `Setting > Backup & reset`, and found that there's an option of `Restore from storage`! And it did restore my contacts and SMS. Ye God because I wanted to restore contact, I was SO SURE it had to be done from Contact setting, and because I never did factory reset, never crossed my mind there would be that option... Thank you very much!  :')

Comment: @1990clb Now what should I do with my question if it's answered here? You write your comment as answered and I accept it, or just remove this question completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if there is a way to export or backup contacts, there is a way to import them again through the same tool or application.

Check in the application settings or options to see if there is a way to import the contacts.